# Compare 2 files in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare two files, A and C, in Python and for some reason the double for loop doesn't seem to work properly:

```
with open(locationA + filenameC,'r') as fileC, open(locationA + filenameA,'r') as fileA:
     for lineC in fileC:
         fieldC = lineC.split('#')
         for lineA in fileA:
             fieldA = lineA.split('#')
             print 'UserID Clicks' + fieldC[0]
             print 'UserID Activities' + fieldA[0]
             if (fieldC[0] == fieldA[0]) and (fieldC[2] == fieldA[2]):
                 print 'OK'
```

Here, only the line of C seems to be compared, but for the other lines, the "A loop" seems to be ignored.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The `difflib` module?

Comment: Once you reach the end of `fileA` in the inner loop on the first iteration of the outer loop, the pointer is at the end of the file. Subsequent attempts to iterate over the file won't do anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is right about the cause of your problem.  You need `fileA.seek(0)` to reset your handle.

Comment: os.system('diff ' + filenameA + ' ' + filenameB).... ok, ok, just joking

Comment: Do you really want to compare every line in A with every line in C? And make each comparison twice?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that once you iterate over `fileA` once you need to change the pointer to the beginning of the file again. 
So what you might do is create two lists from both files and iterate over them as many times as you want. For example:

```
fileC_list = fileC.readlines()
fileA_list = fileA.readlines()
for lineC in fileC_list:
  # do something
  for lineA in fileA_list:
    # do somethins
```

Comment: Better might be to do fileA.seek(0) at the beginning of the first for block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with nested loops (from the point of view of your current problem) is precisely that the inner loop runs to completion for each iteration of the outer loop. So instead, set `lineA` by calling for the next item from the `fileA` iterator explicitly:

```
with open(locationA + filenameC,'r') as fileC, open(locationA + filenameA,'r') as fileA:
     for lineC in fileC:
         fieldC = lineC.split('#')
         lineA = next(fileA)
         fieldA = lineA.split('#')
         print 'UserID Clicks' + fieldC[0]
         print 'UserID Activities' + fieldA[0]
         if (fieldC[0] == fieldA[0]) and (fieldC[2] == fieldA[2]):
             print 'OK'
```

This logic will ignore any extra lines from `fileA` once `fileC` is exhausted, and if `fileC` contains more lines than `FileA` things might also get ugly without special checks.

A different approach might use `itertools.izip()` to collect lines from each file in pairs:

```
import itertools
with open(locationA + filenameC,'r') as fileC, open(locationA + filenameA,'r') as fileA:
for lineC, lineA in itertools.izip(fileC, fileA):
         fieldC = lineC.split('#')
         fieldA = lineA.split('#')
         print 'UserID Clicks' + fieldC[0]
         print 'UserID Activities' + fieldA[0]
         if (fieldC[0] == fieldA[0]) and (fieldC[2] == fieldA[2]):
             print 'OK'
```

I can't think of any specific reason to use one instead of the other, but if the files are of any size at all refuse the temptation to use the builtin `zip()` function instead of `itertools.izip()` - the former returns a list, and so memory usage depends on file sizes, whereas the latter is a generator, and so creates values as they are required.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing all lines from FileA to each line from FileC. That means, for each line of File C, you will read the entire FileA, and (provided you do move the pointer to the beginning of the File A), you would read it again, and again.

It is easier to read them both at the same time while they both have lines
if they are the same, do something, read from both

if they are different, read from the smallest (Line A < Line C, read from File A only; Line C < Line A, read from Line C only)

and make two last loops while there are remaining lines (two loops, one for each file, as you do not know which one ran out of lines)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but it comes up on google when someone is looking for a solution to compare 2 text files in python.

This code worked for me.

You can update the codes and use "with open" instead and fine tune as you like but it does the job.

```
# Ask the user to enter the names of files to compare
fname1 = input("Enter the first filename (text1.txt): ")
fname2 = input("Enter the second filename (text1.txt): ")

# Open file for reading in text mode (default mode)
f1 = open(fname1)
f2 = open(fname2)

# Print confirmation
print("-----------------------------------")
print("Comparing files ", " > " + fname1, " < " +fname2, sep='\n')
print("-----------------------------------")

# Read the first line from the files
f1_line = f1.readline()
f2_line = f2.readline()

# Initialize counter for line number
line_no = 1

# Loop if either file1 or file2 has not reached EOF
while f1_line != '' or f2_line != '':

    # Strip the leading whitespaces
    f1_line = f1_line.rstrip()
    f2_line = f2_line.rstrip()

    # Compare the lines from both file
    if f1_line != f2_line:

        # If a line does not exist on file2 then mark the output with + sign
        if f2_line == '' and f1_line != '':
            print(">+", "Line-%d" % line_no, f1_line)
        # otherwise output the line on file1 and mark it with > sign
        elif f1_line != '':
            print(">", "Line-%d" % line_no, f1_line)

        # If a line does not exist on file1 then mark the output with + sign
        if f1_line == '' and f2_line != '':
            print("<+", "Line-%d" % line_no, f2_line)
        # otherwise output the line on file2 and mark it with < sign
        elif f2_line != '':
            print("<", "Line-%d" %  line_no, f2_line)

        # Print a blank line
        print()

    #Read the next line from the file
    f1_line = f1.readline()
    f2_line = f2.readline()


    #Increment line counter
    line_no += 1

# Close the files
f1.close()
f2.close()
```