# Python newb: What's preventing this function from printing?

Tags: python, xml, csv

#### Background

I haven't worked much with python, but I want to use it to generate some repetitive XML for me. Right now, I just want to parse CSV, then pass those values into the XML stanzas.

There's a catch: I need to rewrite some of the CSV before I write the XML. I have some `if` statements to take care of this for me, and I decided to reduce clutter by moving it to a separate function.

This is where my problem arises. My `writeTypes` function appears to work as intended *but* when I return the re-written csvDict instance, I can no longer print values.

Clearly I am missing something, probably simple - but what? Script with comments below.

#### Script

```
import csv

def parseCSV(vals):

    # read the csv

    dictReader = csv.DictReader(open(vals, 'rb'), fieldnames=['name', 'type', 'nullable', 'default', 'description', '#'], delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # some repetitive xml; I will finish this portion later...

    stanza = '''
    <var name="{0}" precision="1" scale="None" type="{1}">
        <label>{2}</label>
        <definition><![CDATA[@{3}({4})]]></definition>
    </var>'''

    # a function that simply writes new values to dictionary entries 

    writeTypes(dictReader)

    # I'm confused here - nothing is printed to the console. 
    # If i comment my 'writeTypes function, prints as expected

    for i in dictReader:
        print i
        print i['type']


# function to rewrite 'types' key in dictionary set
def writeTypes(d):

    for i in d:
        if i['type'] == 'text':
            i['type'] = 't'
        elif i['type'] == 'boolean':
            i['type'] = 'l'
        elif i['type'] == 'double precision':
            i['type'] = 'd'
        elif i['type'] == 'integer':
            i['type'] = 'i'
        else:
            i['type'] = i['type']

         # unsurprisingly, this function does seem to print the correct values    
        print i

    # it seems as though there's something wrong with this return statement...
    return d
```

#### Example CSV

(public data pulled from .gov site)

```
Name,Type,Nullable,Default,Description,#
control,text,true,,,1,false
flagship,boolean,true,,,1,false
groupid,text,true,,,1,false
hbcu,text,true,,,1,false
hsi,text,true,,,1,false
iclevel,text,true,,,1,false
landgrnt,text,true,,,1,false
matched_n_00_10_11,boolean,true,,,1,false
matched_n_05_10_6,boolean,true,,,1,false
matched_n_87_10_24,boolean,true,,,1,false
name,text,true,,,1,false
name_short,text,true,,,1,false
school,text,true,,,1,false
sector,text,true,,,1,false
sector_revised,text,true,,,1,false
top_50,boolean,true,,,1,false
virginia,boolean,true,,,1,false
```

Comment: `dictReader` is an iterator, it is consumed the first time you iterate over it with a `for` loop.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24268020/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jefftopia, the problem is that your first use of `dictReader` as an iterator "consumes" the whole file, so that there's nothing left to read when you try to iterate through it a second time.

When you do this...

```
# a function that simply writes new values to dictionary entries 

writeTypes(dictReader)
```

... the writeTypes function iterates through the rows of the CSV file, by way of `dictReader`:

```
def writeTypes(d):
    for i in d:
        ...
```

Then you return from that function and try to iterate through `dictReader` **again**. The problem is that `dictReader` now has no data left to read from the underlying file, since it's gone through the whole thing already!

```
# I'm confused here - nothing is printed to the console. 
# If i comment my 'writeTypes function, prints as expected

for i in dictReader:
    print i
    print i['type']
```

When you use a `file` object or most similar objects as an iterator in Python, the iterator "consumes" the file. As a general rule, there's **no way to reliably read a file-like object and then go back to the beginning to read it a second time** (consider the case of a network socket which may stream data only once).

In this particular case, you **could** simply re-open the file a second time before the second pass through the data. (There are even more kludge-y solutions, but I won't show 'em.)

```
# reopen the file in order to read through it a second time
dictReader = csv.DictReader(open(vals, 'rb'), fieldnames=['name', 'type', 'nullable', 'default', 'description', '#'], delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for i in dictReader:
    print i
    print i['type']
```

Multi-pass file processing can sometimes substantially simplify code like this, although it can hurt performance as well for large files. In this particular case, it'd be straightforward to do everything in one pass; you can simply rewrite the code slightly so as to  gather the `type` fields as you iterate through the rows.

Comment: Reopening the file won't fix it unless the changes are saved to the file, and currently they are not being saved.

Comment: @Rob Watts, that's totally irrelevant. The OP's code isn't making any changes to the file, only reading it, so there'd be nothing to re-save in a multi-pass approach.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, @Jefftopia. When you iterate through the `dictReader`, it gives you a **mutable** dict object for every row. You could use something like `for d in dictReader: d['type'] = rewriteTypeValue(d['type'])`, to read each row and then modify the `type` field before you write it out or do something else with it.

Answer (score 3):

dictReader is an iterator, and once it's read through the CSV file, it's exhausted: a further iteration will not do anything.

The way to fix this is to create a new list of dicts in writeTypes, so that you assign the values there rather than in the original. You can then return that list, and iterate through that in the main function.

Comment: To be a little bit more explicit, @Daniel Roseman is suggesting that you cache the contents of the file on the first pass, and use that for the second pass. While this works fine, it's very memory-intensive for large files. Rewriting the whole thing to process each line in a single pass seems like the optimal solution to me.